# app.config + stateProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui.router to handle my app routing, currently my app is small online a couple routes. As of right now they go into app.config, i'd like to spilt out each route configuration based on feature, for example this feature is a for a "Promotion" SPA, how can I go about doing this so I won't clutter my initial app.config js file?

```
$stateProvider
            .state('promotion', {
                controller: 'PromotionsController',
                url: '',
                views: {
                    "list": {
                        controller: 'PromotionsController',
                        templateUrl: templatesRoot + 'Promotion/promotion-list.html'
                    },
                    "editor": { template: "Welcome" }
                }
            })
            .state('promotion-edit',
                {
                    url: '/edit/{id}',
                    views: {
                        "list": {
                            controller: 'PromotionsController', 
                            templateUrl: templatesRoot + 'Promotion/promotion-list.html'
                        },
                        "editor": {
                            controller: ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'promotionService', function ($scope, $stateParams, promotionService) {
                                $scope.promotion = promotionService.getPromotion($stateParams.id)
                                $scope.savePromotion = function () {
                                    // save the promotion
                                    promotionService.savePromotion($scope.promotion, function (data, responseHeaders) {
                                        if (!data.Success) {
                                            toaster.pop({
                                                type: 'error',
                                                title: 'Error',
                                                body: data.Message,
                                                showCloseButton: true
                                            });
                                        } else {
                                            toaster.pop({
                                                type: 'success',
                                                title: "Success",
                                                body: "Successfully saved the promotion",
                                                showCloseButton: true
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                };
                            }],
                            templateUrl: templatesRoot + 'Promotion/promotion-edit.html'
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
            .state('promotion-create',
                {
                    url: '/create',
                    views: {
                        "list": {
                            controller: 'PromotionsController',
                            templateUrl: templatesRoot + 'Promotion/promotion-list.html'
                        },
                        "editor": {
                            controller: 'PromotionsController',
                            templateUrl: templatesRoot + 'Promotion/promotion-create.html'
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate your routes into files. For example:

promotion.js

```
angular.module('AppName').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('promotion', {
            controller: 'PromotionsController',
            url: '',
            views: {
                "list": {
                    controller: 'PromotionsController',
                    templateUrl: templatesRoot + 'Promotion/promotion-list.html'
                },
                "editor": { template: "Welcome" }
            }
        })
}]);
```

Then in your index.html, reference this file:

```
<script src="pathToRoutes/promotion.js"></script>
```

After that you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in a separate files which contain only config blocks.

For example you can have:

```
app/scripts/app.js # not router configuration
app/scripts/routes/promotions.js # pomotions configuration
app/scripts/routes/featureN.js # n-th feature
app/scripts/routes/custom-states-provider.js
```

The last one you will need if you notice a lot of code duplication between the features and you want to make a custom wrapper around the ui router $stateProvider with utility functions. Of course there are other solutions to this problem.